# Doctrine's QueryBuilder returns unexpected Proxies\__CG__\ objects

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to join 2 simple tables having one to one relationship. My problem is that the original result returned by Query Builder is an array consisting of 2 different types of objects:

```
Proxies\__CG__\Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoCategories
Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoGallery
```

I only want to have the `Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoGallery` type of objects in the result.

Table "photo_gallery":

```
CREATE TABLE `photo_gallery` (
  `aid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `string_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `main_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photographer_id` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main_media` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date_taken` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `place_taken` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `allow_comments` enum('true','false') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true',
  `active` enum('true','false') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`),
  KEY `main_category_id` (`main_category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `photo_gallery_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`main_category_id`) REFERENCES `photo_categories` (`aid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=336 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table "photo_categories":

```
CREATE TABLE `photo_categories` (
  `aid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `string_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `head_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` enum('true','false') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you see photo_gallery.main_category_id field is FK referencing to photo_categories.aid. Schema fragment in PhotoGallery.orm.xml referencing this relationship:

```
<one-to-one field="mainCategory" target-entity="PhotoCategories">
    <join-columns>
       <join-column name="main_category_id" referenced-column-name="aid"/>
    </join-columns>
</one-to-one>
```

Fragment from the PhotoGallery entity:

```
/**
 * PhotoGallery
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="photo_gallery", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="main_category_id", columns={"main_category_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoGalleryRepository")
 */
class PhotoGallery
{

    /**
     * @var \Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoCategories
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoCategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_category_id", referencedColumnName="aid")
     * })
     */
    private $mainCategory;
```

I have a PhotoGalleryRepository class, where I'm using a query builder to join those two tables:

```
public function findLatest($params, $keyword = false, $filter_by = false) {
    [...some irrelevant code here...]

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('photoGallery');
    $qb->select(array('photoGallery', 'photoCat'))
        ->innerJoin(
            'Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoCategories',
            'photoCat',
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
            'photoGallery.mainCategory = photoCat.aid'
        )
        ->where('photoGallery.active = ?1')
        ->andWhere('photoCat.active = ?2');

    [...some irrelevant code here...]

    $qb->setParameter(1, 'true')
        ->setParameter(2, 'true')
        ->orderBy($params['orderBy'], 'DESC');

    if (isset($params['offset']) && isset($params['limit'])) {
        $qb->setFirstResult($params['offset'])->setMaxResults($params['limit']);
    }

    try {
        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

        $resultRevised = array();
        foreach ($result AS $photo) {
             //this is the lame part
            if (get_class($photo) == 'Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoGallery') {
                $resultRevised[] = $photo;
            }
        }

        return $resultRevised;
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you see I'm looping through the `$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult()`; to only include `Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoGallery` type of objects.

When I look at the queries ran using Symfony2 profiler, I see that the native MySQL query is absolutely correct.

Why is my original result polluted with `Proxies\__CG__\Azphotos\PhotoBundle\Entity\PhotoCategories` objects and what am I doing wrong here?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can treat the lazy loaded proxy just like it is your entity. The proxy extends your entity class so it will even pass `instanceof` checks. As soon as you call a getter method on the proxy it will hydrate the object. Alternatively, you can configure the query to only return fully hydrated objects.

Comment: True. I can call any getter on a proxy class, and it'll return the correct result. In this case it would be any property of PhotoCategory entity.What I'm confused is why in my results I get a mix of two entities (one of them is represented as a proxy).After I get the results, I don't directly query PhotoCategory entity, but rather through PhotoGallery, e.g.: $photo->getMainCategory()->getTitle().If I change my select to $qb->select(array('photoGallery')), it'll return only photoGallery objects, but upon every call like $photo->getMainCategory()->getTitle() it'll perform an additional DB query.

Comment: Is this "mixture" within my results an expected behaviour then?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected result. The queried root entity will be a fully hydrated instance of your entity class and all associated entities will be proxies until a getter is called on the proxy class that requires Doctrine to hydrate the proxy. After a getter is called on the proxy, Doctrine queries the db and replaces the proxy with a fully hydrated instance of the entity. Hope this makes sense, it's difficult to explain short and concisely.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have known for entities with join association when we write a DQL for that repository class (in your case Photo Gallery Repository), the associated entity (in your case Photo Categories) is lazy loaded on a proxy class. So, that might be why you are getting proxy classes.